# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified for python & java integration

Tags: java, python

I'm trying to execute .java file using my python 3.5. I wrote following code

```
import os
path='Location of my .java file'
os.chdir(path)
import os.path, subprocess
from subprocess import STDOUT, PIPE

def compile_java (java_file):
    subprocess.check_call(['javac', java_file])

def execute_java (java_file):
    cmd=['java', java_file]
    proc=subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = PIPE, stderr = STDOUT)
    input = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin = PIPE)
    print(proc.stdout.read())

compile_java("Hello.java")
execute_java("Hello")
```

But while executing the code, I'm getting error message as `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Can you please help me to solve the issue?

Comment: Are you specifying a fully qualified path in the assignment to the `path` variable? Have you tried specifying a fully qualified path toe javac.exe and java.exe?

Comment: Does the error occur in `compile_java` or `execute_java`? Please provide a stacktrace

Comment: @MultiplyByZer0, I'm getting this error in compile_java.@lit yes the path variable is properly set & JDK/Bin path is given in environmental path variable

Comment: Neither `javac` nor `javac.exe` was found when `CreateProcess` called `SearchPath` to search the application directory (location of python.exe), `%SystemRoot%\System32`, `%SystemRoot%`, `%SystemRoot%\System`, the working directory (maybe; it depends on system configuration), plus the directories in the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: If `javac` can be found in the cmd shell, that means either that it uses a `PATHEXT` extension other than .EXE or that the `PATH` variable incorrectly has the Java bin directory in quotes, which cmd will ignore but to `SearchPath` it's taken as the literal name. The directories in `PATH` should never be quoted.

Comment: Thanks @eryksun.After following your suggestion, it is working now. I'm not getting any error message. But the output from System.out.println() is not coming in my python console. Can you please help me?